# windows app fabric caching

Tags: appfabric-cache

I am having Windows AppFabric Caching with several named caches. Is is possible to have a separate expiration policy for each of the named caches.

If it is possible, kindly let me know how this can be acheived via the configuration file.

Sample Code

```
    <add name="AFCM" type="CelloSaaS.Library.Provider.AppFabricCacheManager, CelloSaaS.Library" RequestTimeout="600"
  RoutingClient="false" LocalCache="true" HostName="192.168.21.3"
  CachePort="22233" CacheHostName="DistributedCacheService" NamedCache="AFCM" InvalidationPolicy="TimeoutBased" DefaultTimeOut="86400"  SecurityMode="None" ProtectionLevel="None" MaxBufferSize = "10000000" />

  <add name="ICM" type="CelloSaaS.Library.Provider.AppFabricCacheManager, CelloSaaS.Library" RequestTimeout="600"
  RoutingClient="false" LocalCache="true" HostName="192.168.0.01"
  CachePort="22233" CacheHostName="DistributedCacheService" NamedCache="ICM" InvalidationPolicy="TimeoutBased" DefaultTimeOut="86400"  SecurityMode="None" ProtectionLevel="None" MaxBufferSize = "10000000" />
```

Kindly note that according to the code, i guess that the policy specified in the 3rd tag is for the named cache called as AFCM. Kindly clarify me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible !
I would highly recommand to try with this great tool : [GUI Administrator for Appfabric 1.1](http://appfabricadmin.codeplex.com/)

If you are a powershell user, you could try

```
Set-CacheConfig YourCacheNameHere -Expirable true -TimeToLive 5
```

(taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921014.aspx)